# How exactly is this variable not being reset with each function call?

Tags: javascript

I created a simple module pattern function that returns an object of methods, in this case theres just one method that adds a creates a div with a unique id and then adds it to a specific section element. The id is created from a private variable in the function named cardId. I'm not understanding how the variable isnt resetting back to 1 with each function call, instead every div returned from the function has a unique id, which implies there is a variable associated another variable named cardId. Could someone shed some light on this or point me to a something that does?

```
let cardTools= function (){
     let cardId=1;

    return {
      addCard: function(){
         let card=document.createElement("div");
         let sec=document.getElementsByClassName("memory-cards")[0];//gets a section

         card.classList.add("card");
         card.id="i";
         card.id+=cardId;
         cardId+=1;

         sec.appendChild(card);

         return card;
         }
     }
}

let tools= cardTools();

let card=tools.addCard(); //id==i1
let card2=tools.addCard(); //id==i2
let card3=tools.addCard(); //id==i3
```

Comment: So you're saying it's working, but you don't understand how?

Comment: Well `cardId` is outside the function `addCard`. It's trapped in a closure (made by the function `cardTools`), But it isn'tdeclared inside `addCard`, so it won't get redeclared each time it is called.

Comment: simple check. How many times do you call `cardTools`? once. So, how many times should `let cardId=1` be executed ...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I've to ask you a question. Are you sure this piece of code is working?

I had to do the following to make it work.

```
let card1 = cardTools().addCard();
console.log(card1.id);
```

When I did this, I was able to see i1 on each call. The code snippet you've posted here gave me syntax errors.

UPDATE:
Sorry, I didn't read your code correctly. I'm pretty sure your code is working. But, when I did this, I got `i1` on each case.

Comment: There must be some mistake with your execution. Since `cardId` is declared outside `addCard()`, it will be increased as no new object of `cardtools()` is created. So the scope of `cardId` will be maintained. So I would suggest you to check the execution again.